# How can I draw a line from shape's connecting point to another shape's connecting point using python-pptx?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I'm trying to draw a line from shape's connecting point to another shape's connecting point using python-pptx. Below is the python source code. When I read the file with PowerPoint and move the shape, the line does not follow. The image is where I read in PowerPoint and the lines do not follow when I move the shape. How can I draw a line between connection points? Would anyone please help me to fix this code?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Jul  9 08:22:36 2020
@author: owner
"""
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Mm
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_SHAPE
from pptx.enum.shapes import MSO_CONNECTOR

prs = Presentation()

# A4 size
prs.slide_width =  Mm(297)
prs.slide_height = Mm(210)

# Slide layout
SLD_LAYOUT_TITLE_AND_CONTENT = 6
slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[SLD_LAYOUT_TITLE_AND_CONTENT]

# Get slide
sld = prs.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)

# Shape1
x1 = Mm(30)
y1 = Mm(50)
w1 = Mm(70)
h1 = Mm(50)

# Shape2
x2 = Mm(200)
y2 = Mm(50)
w2 = Mm(70)
h2 = Mm(50)

# Get autoshape object
shps = sld.shapes

# Shape1 rectangle
shp1 = shps.add_shape(
    MSO_SHAPE.RECTANGLE, x1, y1, w1, h1
)

# Shape2 rectangle
shp2 = shps.add_shape(
    MSO_SHAPE.RECTANGLE, x2, y2, w2, h2
)

# Connector co-ordinate(EMU)
# Shape1
cx1 = shp1.left + shp1.width
cy1 = shp1.top + int(shp1.height/2)
# SHape2
cx2 = shp2.left
cy2 = shp2.top + int(shp2.height/2)

# Draw line from (cx1, cy2) to (cx2, cy2)
line = shps.add_connector(
    MSO_CONNECTOR.STRAIGHT, cx1, cy1, cx2, cy2
)

# File save
prs.save('connector_line.pptx')
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5qzJ.jpg)

Comment: Why does one need start/end x,y values if the connector will be a "smart" connector, attached to set nodes on the shape?

Answer (score 4):

Anchor connector end-points to shape connection points by using the `Connector` methods described in the documentation here:

https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html#connector-objects

Something like:

```
line.begin_connect(shp1, 0)
line.end_connect(shp2, 2)
```

Comment: I appreciate your advice. I was able to do what I wanted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :)  Be sure to accept an answer that resolves your problem by clicking on the checkmark next to that answer. That's how you thank the person for taking the time to help you :)